# TYPO3 form_to_database: How to limit result display to backend usergroup?

Tags: forms, typo3, backend

I use the extension form_to_database to store the results of different forms in the database. Via the backend module "Form results" every backend user is able to view the submitted data.
Is there a way to limit access to the form results to different backend user groups?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that extension, but you should be able to restrict access by the usual ways you control/ grant access for BE-user(groups):

- Normaly every BE-Module has an access control:
  don't grant access for unwanted groups (= grant access only for wanted group)
- Don't grant even read access to this kind of records for unwanted groups
- Don't grant access to the pages/ folders where those records are stored for unwanted groups.

Maybe you need to create an additional group which is a subgroup of other groups as a common group for all those user who should have access.

Comment: This does not work as the backend module "Form  results" must be available for all backend users. 
But within the backend module there must be a possibilty to restrict access to the form results to different users/user groups.